# Recuperar propriedade de um Object Anônimo C# Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou trabalhando com MVC4 e com o RestSharp para acesso a dados via API Rest,

Meu retorno é um objeto do tipo `Object` mas não consigo recuperar uma propriedade específica deste objeto.

Como posso acessar a propriedade?

Segue código da view no qual preciso recuperar a propriedade.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descricao)
    </td>
    <td>
        @{
            var responsavel = item.responsavel.GetType().GetProperty("nome").GetValue(item.responsavel, null);
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.responsavel);
         }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Detalhes", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Deletar", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o codigo que tens actualmente, para ilustrar o problema?

Comment: Já experimentas-te fazes o cast para o tipo de objeto pretendido?

Comment: Eu preciso desta propriedade para exibir na view. Não consegui fazer o cast de maneira nenhuma.

Comment: Porque nao mudar o tipo de retorno da action para o tipo do objecto?

Comment: Desculpe a ignorância, mas poderia ser mais claro?

Comment: Expliquei-me mal.. Qual e' o tipo da variavel `Model`?

Answer (score 1):

O código já está correto. Você pode realizar algumas verificações a mais para evitar `NullReferenceException` na hora de acessar a propriedade:

```
dynamic responsavel = item.responsavel;
var prop = responsavel.GetType().GetProperty("nome");
var nome = ""
if (prop != null) {
    nome = prop.GetValue(responsavel, null);
}
```

Como você não tem um tipo especificado para o objeto (possivelmente ele é anônimo), `dynamic` "arruma" uma tipagem para o objeto.

Comment: Cara funcionou. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Acho que usar dynamic typing ou reflection para criar uma view é errado e leva a código difícil de manter... `Model` não parece ser do tipo correcto, e isso sim, deveria ser corrigido.

Comment: Pode ser, mas o objeto retornado pelo RestSharp é anônimo. Não tem tipo. Ele até pode fazer, mas a resposta resolve corretamente o proposto pela pergunta.

Comment: Sim, a resposta responde à pergunta e resolve o problema, concordo. Mas acho que o OP está a tentar resolver o problema errado. O problema que ele precisa de resolver é saber como passar um objecto correctamente tipado para a view, em vez dum objecto de tipo anônimo.

Comment: O método GetAll da API não consegue transformar em lista automaticamente quando eu seto o tipo do objeto no caso funcionário, ele só atribui quando trabalho com o model desta maneira `public Object responsavel { get; set; }` preciso recuperar um atributo específico na view e o código acima fez isso.